# The Quotients $SO(n)/SO(n-1)$, $O(n)/O(n-1)$ and $SO(n)/O(n−1)$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homogeneous-spaces

The branching laws for the restricted representation of $SO(n)$ with respect to the subgroup $SO(n-1)$ are discussed in this Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_representation). Am I correct in reading from this that any given representation of $SO(n-1)$ can appear in a representation of $SO(n)$ with multiplicity at most $1$? Also what is the name for the corresponding homogeneous space, and does it have any interesting geometric properties?

Also, I am interested in the same questions for $SO(n)/O(n-1)$ and $O(n)/O(n-1)$.

Comment: Quitient is sphere S^n - just consired the map which takes the matrix of SO(N) to its first column - the fiber is SO(N-1). About multiplicities - I  thought it is NOT be multiplicity free, in contrast to SU(n) case... otherwise Gelfand-Tseytlin bases would be not be issue to construct for SO(n)... However I am not fully sure...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the branching is multiplicity free. See e.g. Theorem 8.1.3 and Theorem 8.1.4 in *Symmetry, Representations, and Invariants* by Nolan Wallach and Roe Goodman. The quotient space is a sphere $S^{n-1}$ which you can see for example by calculating the stabilizer of $e_n.$

For orthogonal groups you basically have extra $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action, so for example $SO(n)/O(n-1)$ comes from considering action of $SO(n)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n / \mathbb{Z}_2$ where the action of the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is by multiplication by $-1.$ As for the branching rules in these cases ... it gets a bit complicated and it's hard to find any good reference. What happens here is that the branching is really a statement about Lie algebra representations (or equivalently about the simply connected covering groups $Spin(n)$) and for disconnected groups such as $O(n)$ one has to specify the action of all connected components. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Space_inversion_and_time_reversal for well studied examples.

Comment: The branching from $\mathrm{O}(n)$ to $\mathrm{O}(n - 1)$ is also multiplicity free. A good reference is Robert A. Proctor, "Young Tableaux, Gelfand Patterns, and Branching Rules for Classical Groups", Proposition 10.1. $\mathrm{O}(n)$ isn't connected, but there is still a "highest weight theory": irreducible representations are indexed by $n$-tuples $(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_p,1,\ldots,1,0,\ldots,0)$ of nonnegative integers, where $0 \leq p \leq n/2$, $\lambda_1 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_p \geq 1$, there are $n - 2p$ ones, and $p$ zeroes. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) The branching rule states that irreducible representations of $\mathrm{O}(n - 1)$ with "highest weight" $(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_{n-1})$ occur in the restriction of an irreducible representation of $\mathrm{O}(n)$ with "highest weight" $(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ if and only if $\lambda_1 \geq \mu_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \geq \mu_{n-1} \geq \lambda_n$, in which case it occurs with multiplicity one.

Comment: Oh, and $\mathrm{O}(n) / \mathrm{O}(n - 1) \cong \mathrm{SO}(n) / \mathrm{SO}(n - 1) \cong S^{n - 1}$.

Comment: @Vít: Does is the space SO(n)/O(n-1) have a name? I'm guessing it's not isomorphic to any sphere.

Comment: @Lars It is $\mathbb {RP}^{n-1} $, real projective space.